# Alertmanager webhook does not work when defined on its own

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I configure alertmanager with default receiver which contains both email and webhook:

```
receivers:
- name: infra_email
  email_configs:
   - to: 'xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx'
     send_resolved: true
  webhook_configs:
    - url: 'http://172.22.45.34:55553/'
      send_resolved: false
```

this works fine.

When I try to configure the same as separate receiver:

```
route:
  receiver: 'infra_email'
  group_by: [alertname, severity]
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 4h
  group_wait: 3m
  routes:
    - match:
        alertname: ServerRebooted, HostOutOfDiskSpace, HostOutOfMemory
      receiver: splunk_webhook
      continue: true

receivers:
- name: infra_email
  email_configs:
   - to: 'xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx'
     send_resolved: true

- name: splunk_webhook
  webhook_configs:
    - url: 'http://172.22.45.34:55553/'
      send_resolved: false
```

this does not work.
amtool reports the route as valid:

```
# /usr/local/bin/amtool config routes show
Routing tree:
.
└── default-route  receiver: infra_email
       └── {alertname="ServerRebooted, HostOutOfDiskSpace, HostOutOfMemory}  continue: true  receiver: splunk_webhook

$ alertmanager --version
alertmanager, version 0.20.0 (branch: HEAD, revision: f74be0400a6243d10bb53812d6fa408ad71ff32d)
  build user:       root@00c3106655f8
  build date:       20191211-14:13:14
  go version:       go1.13.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want your webhook be called for `ServerRebooted`, `HostOutOfDiskSpace` and `HostOutOfMemory` alerts and that they are separate alerts.

Your alerts do not match the specified condition. `match:` does exact matching for the labels specified, so adding commas does not work.
Best way would be to use `match_re:` instead and use regular expression:

```
match_re:
  alertname: ServerRebooted|HostOutOfDiskSpace|HostOutOfMemory
```

Alternatively you may consider adding some label to the alerts themselves and then route alerts by that label. If the fact that they are going to splunk is a property of an alert itself then you'd be able to add/remove alerts from the list sent to splunk without touching alertmanager configuration.

Comment: Yes, using match_re seems to work. If the alert matches, and there is property continue: true, it will not get sent also to default receiver?